# Python Gevent is iterating over characters and not the full url

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, concurrency, python-requests, gevent

I'm new to gevent and i have a script which download images and read the urls from a excel file.
I would like to speed up the process and that's where i found gevent

But when i try to run my script it seems to iterate over the characters.
I randomly picked this image from wikimedia

[Wikimedia link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/Ocean_water.jpg/800px-Ocean_water.jpg?20211020104137)

Heres the code

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
import requests
import pandas as pd


from gevent.pool import Pool
p = Pool(4)
path = input("drag in excelfor file-path':")
path = path[1:len(path)-1]
df = pd.read_excel(path, header=None, name=['name', 'url']).dropna(thresh=2)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    
    
        
        url = row['url'].strip()
      

        
        r = p.map(requests.head,url)
        print(r)
```

I have tried making the url as a string but no result.

but when i manually wrtoe the link it works, see below.

url = ['link']

Can you see what i am missing?

Comment: Use itertuples, iterrows is slow... and why not use async ? thats for things like url request far better.

Comment: I suspect that the issue is that `map` applies the function to each element of an iterable; strings are iterable, so `map(requests.head, "string")` will apply `requests.head` to each character in the string.

Comment: There is [grequests](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests).